# Problems trying to deploy MySQL and PHP website to Heroku with ClearDB

Tags: php, mysql, database, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my website to Heroku by following this tutorial: https://scotch.io/@phalconVee/deploying-a-php-and-mysql-web-app-with-heroku

Problem comes at step 11 when I need to import the database file I exported from phpmyadmin into clearDB.

It is mentioned to use this code:

```
mysql -u bafee8afa994  -h us-cdbr-east-05.cleardb.com -p heroku_f677d7 4dc6f < trendymarkt.sql
```

I had replaced the username, hostname, password and sql file with my own. However, every time I press enter after this line, it just keeps showing "-> ", and when I cancel it (ctrl+C), it says I have syntax error.

I don't actually have mysql locally installed since I am using MAMP, but I am trying to activate this code using the MAMP mySQL CLI as indicated here: http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/08/using-mysql-command-line-with-mamp.html so this should not be the problem (?).

Also, in my php file that connects the database, am I suppose to replace the host, username, password and database with the heroku clearDB config? I did it as such:

```
<?php
//setting up database

$servername = "us-cdbr-east-05.cleardb.com"; //was 'localhost:8889'
$dBUsername = "bafee8afa994";   //was 'root'
$dBPassword = "4dc6fc"; //was 'root' or ""
$dbName = "heroku_01fdeda2cc1aa"; //was 'trendymarkt'

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dbName);

if(!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Is it okay to replace the database name? Unsure how it will recognize the database in this case...

I currently have my website deployed onto Heroku, but I am having trouble deploying the MySQL database.

Thank you.

Edit: I managed to run the mysql command, but after entering password, I get this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bafee8afa994'@'ip-10-0-120-40.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: yes it is ok to replace the values

Comment: @nbk Thanks, though how will it recognize the database afterwards? Since the name of the DB is "trendymarkt", if I put "heroku_01fdeda2cc1aa3c", it will still know which one it is?

Comment: you must see in the heroku configuration how your database is named, but the name looks right to me, try it and see if it connects

Comment: @nbk Yes that's how it was named in the heroku config. However, it's not connecting on my deployed website. Do I not have to use this line?: "mysql -u bafee8afa994bd  -h us-cdbr-east-02.cleardb.com -p heroku_f677d75e 4dc6fca < trendymarkt.sql"

Comment: your code looks not right  -p heroku_f677d75e 4dc6fca  this should switched -p is for poassword

Comment: OK I actually got it to work, however once I run that and enter my password. it says "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bafee8afa994bd'@'ip-10-0-120-40.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)"

Comment: then check the data again